# How to check parameter is null in where clause in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell command but stucked on where clause. What i want to achieve is if parameters are not defined, where clause needs to ignore them. I tried this code but couldn't success.

I have parameters;

```
Param(
    [parameter(position=0)]
    [String]
        $JobName,
    [parameter(position=1)]
    [String]
        $JobID
)
```

And where clause which i tried and failed,

```
$Timerjob = Get-SPTimerJob | where { ($_.Id -eq $JobID) -or ($_.Title -eq $JobName) }
```

If `$JobName` or `$JobID` is null (or both of them), where clause should ignore them

how can i achieve this without writing multiple if clause?

Comment: What should happen if the JobID and JobName conflict (eg. they describe two different jobs)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen ID and Name can  be target to two different jobs, there will be no conflict i assume.

Comment: If you just turn the comparisons around (eg. `$_.Title -eq $JobName` -> `$JobName -eq $_.Title`) then your code is fine already. `$null` values will effectively be "ignored", since `$null -eq 123` is false anyway

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen ty for reply. i tried your suggestion and it's like `null -eq $_.Id` since there is no null entry, sadly i'm getting empty result

Comment: @Mathias, I quess "*If $JobName or $JobID is null (or both of them), where clause should ignore them*" means: output *all* `Get-TimerJob`s:. I quess he wants this: `... |where { ($_.Id -eq $JobID) -or ($_.Title -eq $JobName) -or (!$_.Id -and !$_.Title) }`

Comment: @iRon ty for your help. Yes, if user not write a parameter i want to list all Timer Jobs. but `-or (!$_.Id -and !$_.Title)` also returns empty result.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `... |where { ($_.Id -eq $JobID) -or ($_.Title -eq $JobName) -or (!$JobName -and !$JobID) }`

Comment: @iRon and by the time i was trying this one: `|where { (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($JobID) -and $_.Id -eq $JobID) -or ...` but failed i guess. And your answer is correct it's working. Thank you so much, can you post answer? and i will try to make your answer "solved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment:

To retrieve *all* Timer Jobs if both `$JobName` and `$JobID` are empty, you will need to add that condition to the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet:

```
$Timerjob = Get-SPTimerJob |Where-Object {
    (!$JobName -and !$JobID) -or ($_.Id -eq $JobID) -or ($_.Title -eq $JobName)
}
```

This means if both `$JobName` and `$JobID` are empty, the condition `(!$JobName -and !$JobID)` is `$True`. Any condition with the `-or` comparison operator won't be able to change that (to `$false`) causing the whole condition to be true in that matter and all Timer Jobs returned.

In case you would like to make a difference between an empty string filter and a parameter that isn't supplied, you would probably want to do something like this:

```
$Timerjob = Get-SPTimerJob |Where-Object {
    ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('JobName') -and $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('JobID')) -or
    ($_.Id -eq $JobID) -or ($_.Title -eq $JobName)
}
```

In this case you would e.g. still be able to retrieve Time Jobs with an empty title (`-JobName ''`), if even possible.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote but thank you so much for your help. That really works well.